# Bigint arithmetic operation in linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list, bigint

I have two doubly linked list with the unknown length of nodes of numbers.
I need to do add and multiply two lists. What is a good way of solving the problem
? I tried to do with operator overloading +,* but not clear with the algorithms

Main here

```
//get line input from file
while (getline(ifs, line)){

    string operation=" ";
    string num1=" ";
    string num2=" ";
    int operationIndex=0;
    //get string from stringstream
    //delimiter here + - * / to split string to two part
    for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
        if (ispunct(line[i])) {
            operationIndex = i;
        }
    }
    num1 = line.substr(0,operationIndex);
    num2 = line.substr(operationIndex+1);
    operation = line[operationIndex];

    //Dynamic lists
    DoublyLinkedList* l1 = new DoublyLinkedList(num1,digitsPerNode);
    DoublyLinkedList* l2 = new DoublyLinkedList(num2,digitsPerNode);
    DoublyLinkedList* result = new DoublyLinkedList;

    //Do math here
    if (operation == "+") {
        //*result = *l1 + *l2;

    }
    else if(operation == "*"){
        //*result = *l1 + *l2;
    }

    //print answer here
    cout << num1 << operation << num2 << "=";

    result->printList();
    //l1->printList();
    //l2->printList();

    //free lists memory
    delete l1;
    delete l2;
    delete result;
}
```

Overloading here

```
//addition
DoublyLinkedList DoublyLinkedList::operator+(const DoublyLinkedList &l2) const
{
    DoublyLinkedList result;


    return result;
}
//multiplication
DoublyLinkedList DoublyLinkedList::operator*(const DoublyLinkedList &l2) const
{
    DoublyLinkedList result;


    return result;
}
```

Comment: Most people are taught an algorithm for adding integers in primary school. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I know how the math behind but not sure how to change it to C++. I need to check the length of Nodes and not sure if I covered all condition so that the Nodes can align

Comment: A very useful thing is storing the numbers "in reverse" – the least significant digit first (the order you'll be adding in rather than the order you write the numbers). Then you don't need to worry so much about the respective lengths.